# Проблема с setInterval в JS

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер! Возникла проблема с решением задачи. 
Есть 9 блоков (массив mult от 0 до 8). 
Задача: циклически изменять фон каждого блока через некоторый интервал времени. 
Для изменения цвета фона есть функция colorChange(i, color). К ней претензий нет. 
Проблема в том, что фон меняется только при первом прохождении по блоками от 0 до 8. Затем, когда счетчик возвращаю в исходное значение 0, чтобы снова пройтись по всем блоками, цвет фона больше не меняется. 
Ниже мой код.

```
    var mult = document.getElementsByClassName('mult');

    function colorChange(i, color) {
      mult[i].classList.add(color);
    }

    var i = 0;
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
      if (i != 0) {
        colorChange(i-1, 'white');
      }

      if (i === 9) {
        i = 0;
      }
      colorChange(i, 'yellow');
      i++;

      }, 300);
```

Comment: Какую ошибку в консоли видите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что раз добавив класс элементам вы его потом не удаляете. Вот пример: если добавляется класс `white`, то удаляется класс `yellow` и наоборот.

```js
 var mult = document.getElementsByClassName('mult');

 function colorChange(i, color, dcolor) {
   mult[i].classList.add(color);
   mult[i].classList.remove(dcolor)
 }

 var i = 0;
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
   if (i != 0) {
     colorChange(i - 1, 'white', 'yellow');
   }

   if (i === 9) {
     i = 0;
   }
   colorChange(i, 'yellow', 'white');
   i++;

 }, 300);
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="mult">111</span>
<span class="mult">222</span>
<span class="mult">333</span>
<span class="mult">444</span>
<span class="mult">555</span>
<span class="mult">666</span>
<span class="mult">777</span>
<span class="mult">888</span>
<span class="mult">999</span>
```